# Kubectl run - doesn't create replicaset

Tags: kubernetes

I am using below command to create my pod

```
kubectl run pingpong --image alpine ping 1.1.1.1
```

This command works good, but doesn't create replicaset.

How can I create a replicaset with this command too? I tried below

```
kubectl create deployment pingpong --image alpine ping 1.1.1.1
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From kubernetes version 1.18 `kubectl run` does not create deployment anymore because all the generators were deprecated.

You should use below command to create a deployment which internally creates a replicaset.

```
kubectl create deployment pingpong --image=alpine
```

Please note you can not pass a command like `ping 1.1.1.1` in the above command.

If you want to add a command you need to edit the deployment created above using `kubectl edit deployment pingpong`or use a yaml to create it in first place.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alpine-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alpine
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: alpine
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: alpine
        image: alpline
        command: ["<Your command here>"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Well if you are on the kubernetes version above 1.18 then the first command only create pod.

So if you want to create pod,deployment and replicaset

use this command

```
 kubectl create deployment pingpong --image=alpine
```

and to list above created command objects use `kubectl get pod,rs,deploy`